# String index out of range Python

Tags: python, types, int

Trying to write a code at the moment that basically tests to see if the letter that lies at r (so here (2,3)) is equal to a particular letter or string.

```
def test():

txt = "test.txt"
r = (2,3)
if txt[r[0]][r[1]] == 'l':
    return (True)
elif txt[r[0]][c[1]] == "m":
    return (False)
elif txt[r[0]][c[1]] == "b":
    return (True)
```

But i keep getting an error. The error dialogue is this:

```
if txt[r[0]][r[1]] == 'l':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I have no idea what im doing wrong considering i had it working earlier today.
Also, before you ask, i have to code it this way for a particular reason.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `(2,3)` instead of `2` as index? - and what is `c`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note,

```
if txt[r[0]][r[1]] == 'l':
```

should be written as

```
if txt[r[0]:r[1]] == 'l':
```

and similarly other usage should be changed

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do?  What would your return be?

The reason it doesn't work is this:

```
r = (2,3)
txt[r[0]][r[1]] -> txt[2][3]

txt[2] == 's'
s[3] -> IndexError
```

As mentioned by @Abhijit, if you are trying to grab the character by doing a slice, then

```
txt[r[0]:r[1]] is correct.
```

However, if you are always doing a slice that grabs one character, meaning your r tuple is always of the form (N, N+1), like (2, 3), then you may want to change your strategy.

Note that for your given example you could do:

```
if any([letter in txt for letter in ['l', 'b']]):
    return True
```

If you need to check for actual slices in the text and not just a single character, then the above will still work.

```
if any([letter_group in txt for letter_group in ['te', 'st']]):
    return True
```

or even:

```
if any([letter in txt for letter in 'lb']]):
    return True
```

for example...

Comment: im trying to test whether or not the letter is in that coordinate.
in the first example where it equals "l", i want it to return true if the particular element is "l"

Comment: Ok, so "test.txt" is a _file_ not the string?

Comment: Right, so if you are only looking for a single character, then you don't need to use a slice, you can just use an index offset like `txt[r]` where `r = 2`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do a slice to check if a character is present at a certain location. For example:

```
txt = 'test.txt'
if txt[2] == 's':
    print 'runs'
```

So if you coordinate is `(2, 3)` then you only need to use the first value:

```
txt = 'test.txt'
coord = (2, 3)
if txt[coord[0]] == 's':
    print 'runs'
```

Comment: While I agree with you that a slice is not needed if the range is always the form (N, N+1), if it isn't, or the OP needs to check for mutli-character matches, then a slice is still needed.

Comment: @sberry: True indeed, the slice approach is still needed in that case.